# Change family name in Revit

Tags: vb.net, rename, revit

I am trying to write a macro to rename the family name in revit. By reference the sample of renaming views from this link:

http://archsmarter.com/rename-everything-revit-macros/

I substitute the "family" instead of "view" in the code, but it cannot run unfortunately. Can anyone suggest me how to modify it?

```
    Public Function getAllFamilies(curDoc As Document) As List(Of Family)
    'get all families


    Dim curCollector As New FilteredElementCollector(curDoc)
    curCollector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.ost_families)

    Dim familyList As New List(Of Family)
    For Each curFamily As Family In curCollector.ToElements
        familyList.Add(curFamily)
    Next

    Return familyList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you list above seems to be attempting to retrieve all families in the document. That is an easy task, a one-liner. However, I am surprised by your attempt to use 'BuiltInCategory.ost_families'. I am sure that does not exist. Furthermore, you probably cannot rename a family just like that. Do you know what you are doing at all? Are you aware of the meaning of family definition, family type, family instance? Maybe you would in fact wish to rename family instances? That would make more sense. I would suggest that you gather some experience using Revit from an end user point of view, to understand what it is that you actually want to achieve, and then work through the first steps of getting started with the Revit API, especially the DevTV and My First Revit Plugin tutorials:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2

That will fully answer your question above and many, many more besides.

I hope this helps and wish you much fun and success getting started with the Revit API!